# Tuleap OpenALM artifact part of multiple hierarchies

Tags: hierarchy, tuleap

As I am new to Tuleap OpenALM I am trying to figure out how to make an artifact be part of multiple hierarchies.  Effectively I have created a tracker to hold business use cases and another one in a hierarchy under it to hold variants of these use cases.  Epics, User Stories, and Tasks are in this hierarchy under this variant.  (Business Use Case \ Variant \ Epics \ User Stories \ Tasks)  Additionally I have created a hierarchy holding Releases and Sprints (Releases \ Sprints).  When performing sprint planning the Epics and User Stories do now show up under the release for selection.  Is it possible to configure the Epics and User Stories to be under both hierarchies?  Does anyone have any other potential solutions?  Effectively I am attempting to link or tag the Epics and User Stories with an attribute of Business Use Case and corresponding Variant, and be able to have the use cases and variants in an easy to manage location.  Furthermore I want to be able to generate reporting based on completion of stories under each of the use cases and variants.  Any advice is much appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for an artifact to be under multiple hierarchies at the moment.But be careful, there is a difference between what we call hierarchy and what you're doing during a sprint planning or a release planning inside the AgileDashboard plugin:

- On the AgileDashboard plugin you're not adding User stories under the Releases or Sprints, you're just linking them together.
- In the Tracker Administration you can define Hierarchy and then when you link (using an ArtifactLink field) an Artifact A (in tracker A) that is under an Artifact B (in tracker B) following the hierarchy you defined, Artifact A will be visible in the Artifact B children and Artifact B will be visible as Artifact A parent.

So, If I understand correctly your use case (which might not be the case),  just link User stories and Epics with the corresponding Business cases/Variant and if your hierarchy is correctly defined you should find them in the children/parent definitions. For the Release/Sprint planning part, continue to do so using the AgileDashboard plugin.

Please let me know if I answered correctly your question.